# Regex Split String

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Я не очень хорошо разбираюсь в регулярных выражениях, и мне требуется помощь.

```
(0, 'Тест, тест', 'Описание (Один, два, три) клан "Охотники"', 'Лог\'да')
```

Нужно разбить текст через ",". Но проблема в том, что текст в кавычках тоже может содержать запятую. А так-же текст может содержать символ "**\'**" для имен.

На данный момент, я не к чему не пришел.

Нужно получить такой вывод:

```
0 
'Тест, тест' 
'Описание (Один, два, три) клан "Охотники"' 
'Лог\'да'
```

Вот все что имею на данный момент:

```
string token = @"(?<!\([^()]*)(?:(?:,))";
string[] arg = Regex.Split(currentLine, token);
```

Comment: Пробовали CSV-парсер?

Comment: Нет, я даже не знаю что это такое. Как я уже говорил, столкнулся с рег. выражениями в первые. Сейчас попробую поискать инфу в Google

Comment: Вот тут пример - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542996/how-to-split-csv-whose-columns-may-contain/6543418#6543418. Кстати, `(?:(?:,))` = `,`

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь